# rabbitmq with MQTT plugin and X509 authentication not recognize the username specified in cert's common name

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, x509

I've configured the rabbitmq instance with MQTT plugin. I need to configure the MQTT plugin to achieve the auth with x509 certs (so with ssl). I put these configs in the configuration file:

```
mqtt.listeners.tcp.default = 0.0.0.0:1883
mqtt.listeners.ssl.default = 0.0.0.0:8883
mqtt.allow_anonymous = false
mqtt.vhost            = /
mqtt.exchange         = amq.topic
mqtt.subscription_ttl = 86400000
mqtt.prefetch         = 10

ssl_options.cacertfile = /certs/rootCACert.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = /certs/server-cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /certs/server-key.pem
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert  = true
mqtt.ssl_cert_login = true
ssl_cert_login_from = common_name
```

When I put the cers on the mqtt explorer client in the rabbit log I can see thies messsage:

```
[error] <0.1292.0> MQTT login failed for user '', authentication failed: Refused
[error] <0.1292.0> MQTT connection 172.21.0.1:37746 -> 172.21.0.4:8883 is closing due to an authentication failure
```

I already put the user called like the common name of the certificate and with no password with all permissions.

If I do the login with username and password with another account, I can login succesfully.

Can you help me to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

this was not so much to go on but:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html

Section: "Virtual Host as Part of Username", "Authentication with TLS/x509 client certificates".
"The plugin can authenticate TLS-enabled connections by extracting a name from the client's TLS (x509) certificate, without using a password."
[...]
Note that:The authenticated user must exist in the configured authentication / authorisation backend(s).

Create a user in RMQ equal to the CN of the certificate and do a new test. (and dont use the password in the URI)

Example

```
amqps://USER-NAME-EQUAL-TO-CN-OF-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE:@server-name?cacertfile=/path/to/cacert.pem&certfile=/path/to/cert.pem&keyfile=/path/to/key.pem&verify=verify_peer
```

Experiment with

```
verify=verify_peer, verify=verify_none
```

To see if you have some certificate error.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-query-parameters.html